# Arithmetic Expression Validation

Tags: javascript

Is there any existing javascript library that would return true or false depending whether an arithmetic expression is valid or not?

Here are some examples:

1. abs((x + y) * 2)   : true
2. ceil(x)   : true
3. x / y + 2   : true
4. x/y+2   : true
5. a + 10 /   : false
6. a b + 4   : false

As you can see in my example, number 5 will return false since the expression is not finished and also false for number 6 since there are no operation between a and b, hence they're invalid.

**If no javascript library is existing for this, what would be a good way to check if it is valid?**

Comment: What have you tied so far. Please show us your try.

Comment: Following was my approach:
1. Convert the string into postfix expression.


2. Check for valid postfix expression by the following:

   a. take a counter with value 0;

   b. Finding a literal, increments the counter

   c. Finding a binary operator, decrements the counter

   d. Finding a unary operator, no operation on the counter

   e. If counter values 1, valid postfix else invalid


But I am not sure is this approach correct of not.
Or I should use an existing library for this.

Comment: @Esha this is definitely how you'd go about it if you wrote your own parser. That *does* involve writing your own parser for it, however, and this is not a trivial task. It's usually better to use an existing product instead of reinventing it. Unfortunately, StackOverflow does not accept questions for software suggestions. A more appropriate question would be if you find a library to use but aren't sure how exactly to do it or if you do write your own parser and get stuck on some problem when implementing it.

Comment: @VLAZ Actually, I tried to find such library but could not find any, that would help me with this. Therefore, I wanted to know is there any such library exists or I need to write down my own parser.

Comment: @Esha unfortunately, I'm not familiar with parsing libraries. It sounds like something that would exist but I really never had to use one, hence I don't know any, much less any I'd even be able to recommend.

Comment: @VLAZ No issues. Thank you. I hope I could get help from someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to leverage javascript's `eval` function. In the `isValid` function below I do the following:

1) Add a space to both sides of the expression (makes regex matching easier).

2) Prefix any string of multiple letters with `Math.` which changes things like `ceil(1.5)` to `Math.ceil(1.5)`. Otherwise javascript complains that `ceil` is not defined.

3) Replace every letter that isn't part of a string of multiple letters with a `1`. Otherwise javascript complains that things like `x` are not defined.

4) Checks if evaluation the expression results in a number result. If yes, the expression is valid else it's invalid.

```js
function isValid(origExp) {
 const exp = (' ' + origExp + ' ')
  .replace(/([a-z]{2,})/gi, 'Math.$1')
  .replace(/([^a-z])[a-z]([^a-z])/gi, '$11$2')
  .replace(/([^a-z])[a-z]([^a-z])/gi, '$11$2');

 try {
  return !isNaN(eval(exp));
 } catch (e) {
  return false;
 }
}

const expressions = [
 'abs((x + y) * 2)',
 'ceil(x)',
 'x / y + 2',
 'x/y+2',
 'a + 10 /', //invalid
 'a b + 4', //invalid
 'abs((x + y) * ceil(2.5)) + A*b/c-d+e',
 'abs((x + y) * ceil(2.5)) + A*b/c-de', //invalid
 'abs((x + y) * ceil(2.5)) + A*b/c-d(e)', //invalid
 'abs((x + y) * ceil(2.5)) + A*b/c-d(+e)', //invalid
 'abs((x + y) * ceil(2.5)) + A*b/c-d+(e)'
];

expressions.forEach(exp => {
 console.log(exp, isValid(exp));
});
```

Comment: Sure, no problem : )